# Install Indigo on ubuntu 15.04 [vivid]

Tags: ros, gazebo, ubuntu, add-dependencies, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 15.04 from source.

After trying to install dependencies in the catkin workspace I'm getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
gazebo_ros: No definition of [gazebo] for OS version [vivid]
gazebo_plugins: No definition of [gazebo] for OS version [vivid]
```

I have tried working through the answer in [this previously asked question](http://answers.ros.org/question/196076/building-indigo-on-1410/). But, unfortunately the same error message persists when trying to install dependencies.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224359/install-indigo-on-ubuntu-15.04-%5Bvivid%5D/) by [homesick-nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25641/homesick-nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've managed to get this up and running. I just had to downgrade my ubuntu. Now using 14.04. Thanks

---

Originally posted by [homesick-nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25641/homesick-nick/) with karma: 26 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0